# What is the effect of resistance in a stepper motor coil?

Tags: stepper-motor

Given two bi polar stepper motors with the following resistance in their coils, can any important properties(voltage, current, power, etc) be concluded from the difference in resistance?

| Motor | AB | CD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Motor 1 | 2.9 ohm | 2.9 ohm |
| Motor 2 | 43.6 ohm | 43.3 ohm |

For context, I'm trying to reuse scavenged parts, and want to see if there are ways to learn how bi polar stepper motors work if the part number doesn't lead to a datasheet.

Comment: To the downvoter, could you comment on what I could do to improve this question?

Comment: More clues are needed. Age? Size? What they were used for? (might help estimate torque). Do you have a programmable controller? Motor one is probably designed to run on constant current via PWM. Find a spec for a motor with similar size and coil resistance. Set your controller to the low current limit and try it.

Comment: Motor 2 is more puzzling. It isn't going to work well with a typical controller, many have a minimum current of 1 A. And you don't want to use 40+ Volts.

Comment: The second motor is a stepper motor from a flatbed scanner. I have gotten it moving using a generic stepper driver with a low current. This question was mostly me being interested in learning if there's anything I could do to figure out more about the motor or if I simply have to run it at an estimated safe level (aka thermals staying low), and then forever wonder what the actual specs are.